# Package 'openjdk-11-jdk' has no installation candidate

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, openjdk

When trying to install OpenJDK 11 in Ubuntu, I got an error

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-11-jdk
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package openjdk-11-jdk is a virtual package provided by:
  oracle-java13-installer 13.0.2-1~linuxuprising0
  oracle-java11-installer-local 11.0.6-1~linuxuprising0
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'openjdk-11-jdk' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy openjdk-11-jdk` to the question. It seems that you have added [linuxuprising java PPA](https://launchpad.net/~linuxuprising/+archive/ubuntu/java). Do you plan to use this PPA?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does APT choose the specific package to install in order to provide a virtual package needed as a dependency?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/738980/how-does-apt-choose-the-specific-package-to-install-in-order-to-provide-a-virtua)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To install OpenJDK 11 in Ubuntu, use the commands listed below.

1. Add the repository

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openjdk-r/ppa
```

2. Update package list

```
sudo apt-get update
```

3. Install `openjdk-11-jdk`

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk
```

Comment: "apt-get install software-properties-common" for the add-apt-repository command.

Answer (score 2):

I had this error while building a `Dockerfile`. The solution was to install `default-jre` instead:

```
sudo apt-get install -y default-jre
```